# What pattern am I using in this example of Node.js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

```
'use strict';

var type = {};

type.image = require('./search.image.js');
type.video = require('./search.video.js');
type.social = require('./search.social.js')

function search (query, formatter, type) {

    var objectToUse = type['type'];

    objectToUse.setFormatter = formatter;
    objectToUse.setQuery = query;

    objectToUse.exec(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
}
```

I'm trying to dynamically call a homemade search engine for different types of media. It requires different parsers and to have the data returned in a common format. I'm curious what type of pattern I'm using. If each of the search engines use common code I'll use a mixin. However, I'm curious what is the best pattern to evoke each? And, which pattern this most resembles?

Comment: I suppose it most closely resembles the strategy pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern, although with the strategy pattern you can generally "choose" your strategy at run time. In this case the strategy has to match the type of the data, so perhaps it's just a form of polymorphism (i.e. you could do this with inheritance, you're just not able to because you don't have access to the code).

Comment: The image and video search are very much alike using the same source while finding all social network links for a term will require scraping a page or two and matching facebook or myspace links. Strategy Pattern seems like the correct solution. ["Using Strategy objects versus subclasses can often result in much more flexible code since you're creating a suite of easily swappable algorithms."](http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-strategy/)

Comment: Yes it's certainly close to the strategy pattern.  The only slight wrinkle is you don't really have free choice on which strategy to use.  It is very closely related to the data type, so it's a bit of a hybrid.

Comment: I'm to trying to level up one here. I don't understand not having free choice on which strategy to use. In [this](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/strategy-design-pattern) example, there are three strategies which in the real world would require an api request similar to my situation. It is up to the user to decide which search type to use. Is the search type, i.e. image or video, the data type? Wow in javascript we don't force the class type. So this is duck typing? Each one of the search types require a setQuery and exec public method but there is no way to enforce that.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the code, but you pass in an object (type) and then look at a "type" field on it.  I was assuming this object was given to you and so the code then determined the "formatter" etc based purely on the "type" of the passed parameter (also called "type" which is a bit confusing).  So a bit like using a virtual method table.  But if the "type" parameter is purely a choice of strategy - then yes perhaps it is a proper strategy pattern. Looking at the code again you never use the "type" parameter again so I'm thinking this is the case now.

Comment: I guess that is the point of patterns. I was trying to accomplish something and there was already a solved pattern -- I just didn't know which one it was. If you created an answer I would mark it solved because having a pattern to follow is saving me a lot of time from reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be the Strategy Pattern. From Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the
>   policy pattern) is a software design pattern that enables an
>   algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime.
>
> The strategy pattern 
>   defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each algorithm, and makes
>   the algorithms interchangeable within that family. Strategy lets the
>   algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.[1] Strategy is
>   one of the patterns included in the influential book Design Patterns
>   by Gamma et al. that popularized the concept of using patterns to
>   describe software design.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from this piece of code, @James Gaunt seems to be right about the strategy. 
This could be a nicer way to achieve it, where you don't require an unwanted code:

```
'use strict';

function search (query, formatter, type) {

    var objectToUse = require('./search.' + type + '.js');

    objectToUse.setFormatter = formatter;
    objectToUse.setQuery = query;

   objectToUse.exec(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
}
```